# How do I create a html line divider in shopify that resembles my design attached below?

Tags: line, shopify, divider

I'm trying to recreate the attached image below inside of a custom html field on my website using HTML code only

---

. Can you share advice on where is best practice to place this custom code too please (e.g.inside the liquid.theme or should I create a custom HTML field in the content editor)? Thank you kindly for guidance beautiful people! [image: custom line divider]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where exactly are you trying to add the image? (Product page, home page, etc.)

First you need to upload the image to Shopify in `Settings -> Files` and copy the url. Then add the url to the image tag `<img src="your-image-url.png" alt="">` and finally place that line of code in your template file.

Something else you can do if you are familiar with Sketch/Adobe software, is create the image in one of those programs and export the SVG code. Then use that code in your template file.